# Как правильно сделать валидацию формы input в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать запрет на добавление такого же объекта? И как сделать проверку на year>1900?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Car from './Car/Car'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cars: [],
            pageTitle: 'React components',
            showCars: true,
            inputValues: {name: "", year: ""}
        }
    }

    toggleCarsHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            showCars: !this.state.showCars
        })
    }

    onChangeHandler = e => {
        debugger;
        this.setState({
            inputValues: {...this.state.inputValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}
        })
    };

    onSubmitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            cars: [...this.state.cars, {name: this.state.inputValues.name, year: this.state.inputValues.year}]
        })
    };

    onChangeName(name, index) {
        const car = this.state.cars[index]
        car.name = name
        const cars = [...this.state.cars]
        cars[index] = car
        this.setState({cars})
    }


    deleteHandler(index) {
        const cars = this.state.cars.concat()
        cars.splice(index, 1)
        this.setState({cars})
    }

    render() {
        const divStyle = {
            textAlign: 'center'
        }

        let cars = null;


        if (this.state.showCars) {
            cars = this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
                return (
                    <Car
                        key={index}
                        name={car.name}
                        year={car.year}
                        onDelete={this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index)}
                        onChangeName={event => this.onChangeName(event.target.value, index)}
                    />
                )
            })
        }
        return (
            <div style={divStyle}>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <li><a href="/about">About page</a></li>
                <br/>
                <button
                    onClick={this.toggleCarsHandler}
                >Toggle cars
                </button>

                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
                    <input
                        onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={"name"}
                        value={this.state.inputValues.name}
                    />
                    <input
                        onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                        name="year"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={"year"}
                        value={this.state.inputValues.year}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.toggleMyCarsHandler}>Add car</button>
                </form>
                <div style={{
                    width: 400,
                    margin: 'auto',
                    paddingTop: '20px'
                }}>
                    {cars}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Просто проверяете в onChangeName...

Comment: @RTW onChangeName меняет name уже в созданном компоненте. А я бы хотела при вводе проверить, есть ли уже компонент с таким name. Если есть - запретить добавлять новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1.**

Добавляете в state переключатель для доступности нажатия кнопки Add car

```
this.state = { canAdd: true }
```

Отображаете кнопку в зависимости от этого состояния:

```
this.state.canAdd ? <button type="submit" onClick={this.toggleMyCarsHandler}>Add car</button> : <button>Такая машина уже есть</button>
```

В onChangeHandler или что у вас там ловит новую машину проверяете есть ли такая машина и меняете состояние canAdd с true на false и наоборот.

**Вариант 2.**

В onSubmitHandler проверяете если такая машина и не производите добавление существующей + отправляете как-то сообщение об ошибке.

П.С. И переходите уже на хуки, хватит мучатся с классами.

Comment: в onSubmitHandler не могу понять саму логику как отловить есть ли такая машина.. Пыталась так if(this.state.cars.name !== this.state.inputValues.name){*меняю state*}. Не выходит

Comment: @AnnaRostova cars - это массив, используйте итерацию. this.state.cars.some(car=> car.name===this.state.inputValues.name) // false - ок, true - останавливаем дальнейшие действия.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!